# AppDelegate global variable holds NULL value all time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I am facing very strange problem.. For my project I made 3 different modules now I am integrating them all..My problem is none of my global variable can hold values..It holds **NULL** all the time..

for example have a look at my PickerView code:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)rowinComponent:(NSInteger)component 
{ 
  am=(AppMakerAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]; 
  NSString *domainName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@" , [array objectAtIndex:row]]; 
  am.url=domainName; 
  txtnewscategory.text = domainName; 
  am.catagory_title=[title1 objectAtIndex:row]; 
  NSLog(@"Domain:%@ --> %@ ",domainName,[array objectAtIndex:row]); 
}
```

Here I get **"domainName"** value exactly but when its assigned to global variable am.url it shows null value.. 
Same case for **"am.catagory_title"**

Note:

1) **url** and **catagory_title** are declared in AppDelegate and both are **NSString** datatype.

2) **am** is appdelegate object and used like this..

```
  Appmaker_NewsInfoAppDelegate *am;
  am=(Appmaker_NewsInfoAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
```

Can anyone tell me what Am i doing wrong?? the code works perfectly at original project from where I exported it but doesn't when exported to integrate it.

Thanks..

Edit :

3) in  Appmaker_NewsInfoAppDelegate.h(Delegate class where global variables are declared)

```
  NSString *url;


  @property(retain,nonatomic) NSString *url;
```

Comment: What is `Appmaker_NewsInfoAppDelegate`? can you post the code where you define it?

Comment: have you init and synthesize the url in appDelegate?

Comment: Have you alloc category_title and url in appDelegate in ApplicationDidLaunchFinishing method ? and also check that you have synthesize it or not

Comment: NSString *url;
@property(retain,nonatomic) NSString *url;

Comment: @ Saphrosit : Appmaker_NewsInfoAppDelegate is delegate class where I declare all global variables..

Answer (score 0):

In case you didn't declare them as `@property (retain)`, `am.url` needs to be retained, because `stringWithFormat` gives you an autoreleased object that won't survive this method call if not retained.

The same for `catagory_title`.

Retain them like this:
    am.url = [domainName retain];

But don't forget to release the previous value if you assign them elsewhere:

```
if (am.url != nil) { [am.url release]; }
am.url = [domainName retain];
```

Comment: in .h :

     NSString *url;
     @property(retain,nonatomic) NSString *url;

Comment: I have retained and released both variables..Its the same code from where i exported it..It works fine there..

Answer (score 0):

Verify the property being set to "url" attribute of your app delegate. I hope it is not assign, instead you should use retain or copy.

In the sample code provided by you the domainName is an autoreleased object.